# get current page and total page for pdf in an iframe - pdf.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

The pdf viewer from [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) has it built in to show the current page out of total pages:

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

I have a pdf embedded on my page within an iframe.

Is it possible to use this on my page so that

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Is filled with the same information of `currentpage / totalpages` and if current page isn't possible, just a **totalpages** count would be a satisfactory fallback.

I tried accessing the `ID` of the `iframe`, but was getting **cross-domain rejections**.

Comment: all you can do is set options for the container navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host the viewer on your web site to not receive cross-domain rejection -- these rejections is a browser protection and you will not be able to circumvent them. Once it's on the same domain, you can access iframe's contentWindow and PDFViewerApplication object.

Comment: More on the subject see the Risk Factors section at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes I was planning on trying hosting the viewer.html as a page on my webpage and changing the references, it's not ideal due to the platform we're using - but should do the trick!